# Connection to the Internet dropping randomly

Tags: linux, networking, networkmanager, wpa-supplicant, void-linux

Since some weeks I have been having problems with the WiFi, first, upon boot, there would not be connection to the Internet even though NetworkManager is telling me that the network connection is there.

Then I was just restarting the NetworkManager service and then the connection would be established for the rest of the session.
Now the situation degenerated to the point of being crippling, the connection would be lost and reacquired randomly, the outage lasting several seconds or minutes.
Still, NM tells me that I am connected to the WiFi and the service is up and running. If I ping a site, it does it, until suddenly the connection is dropped:

`64 bytes from wa-in-f147.1e100.net (64.233.184.147): icmp_seq=121 ttl=104 time=33.6 ms`

`64 bytes from wa-in-f147.1e100.net (64.233.184.147): icmp_seq=122 ttl=104 time=33.6 ms`

`From 192.168.0.238 icmp_seq=134 Destination Host Unreachable`

`From 192.168.0.238 icmp_seq=135 Destination Host Unreachable`

I can bring the connection back by restarting the NM service or disconnecting from the WiFi and connecting again with the nm-applet, just for the connection to be lost again at a random time, sometimes after just some seconds.
I tried to disable the NM service and activate dhcpcd and wpa_supplicant, but seems that with this config it keeps doing the same.

`ip address; ip route` give the same result when there is connection and when there isn't.

Also `ip -br link show`, no difference: `<BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP>`

I can even issue a `nmcli d wifi list` and it will show me my WiFi SSID, with 100% signal and full of green bars. For what NM is concerned, internet is right there, wide open.
Ah, BTW, this happens in my main laptop, a x220, in my old Toshiba Satellite from 2008, which I haven't updated in several weeks (same distro), there is no issues, so I do not think the router is to blame.

At this point I am kind of out of ideas, if somebody has seen something similar and can support it would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: While you are running a ping to Google or whoever, have you also simultaneously done a ping to your gateway to see if that connection drops as well?

Comment: any chance the router is the problem? can you try to plug non-wireless signal into it and test if this works?

Comment: @cutrightjm: now I did, and it also drops. If I try to ping my gateway when the connection is already down: `ping: socket: Address family not supported by protocol`

Comment: @Effie: it can be, I connected with an Ethernet cable and seems that the connection is stable after some hours. I have received this router from the ISP relatively recently, but 1.- This didn't happened immediately upon receiving it, I am sure the problem started after an update, and 2.- this does not happen (at least not so bad) in the old Toshiba, and not at all in the Windows 10 laptop from work, however in my ThinkPad is a total disaster.